# How to call WCF Service with javascript passing username and password

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have a WCF Service:

> http://ServerName/ProjName/TestService.svc

with a method `GetDetails` that takes in one argument. Using REST the url would be

> http://ServerName/ProjName/TestService.svc/GetDetails/{ItemID}

where `ItemID` is a parameter

I have changed the endpoint from SOAP to wsHttpBinding endpoint and added custom authentication and a certificate. Now I need to figure out a way to call the WCF Service with javascript, passing it not only a parameter, but also username and password information.

Can anyone help? I have never done this before and was not able to fund anything useful on google or stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the WCF service with some out-of-the-box .NET mechanism like an automatically generated proxy class, proxy generated by the interface or something similar? As far as I know, the authentication method can also be configured for the service.

Comment: I was able to connect using C# console app. I just need to do this with javascript

Answer (score 0):

using jquery the option $.ajax allows you to specify a username and password:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '',
   method: 'POST',
   username: 'foo',
   password: 'bar'
   ...//other parameters
});
```

I'm not sure if it's the kind of username and password that your WCF expects, but you can try. Another option, you can create a proxy (using webapi for example) where you can pass the information, and the webapi will connect to your WCF service.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I tried that and got 400 Bad request error. Checked the Auth headers and Go `No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.`